# How to enable lighting dashboard on Salesforce Android mobile app

Tags: dashboard

I need to enable lighting dashboard on Salesforce Android mobile app..
Currently the dashboard is visible, but getting trimmed on the application.
I don't get the option to enable mobile view for this dashboard.